# What is creating the generated/autoconf.h?

Tags: linux, kernel, make

We're trying to build a piece of software that demands the kernel source, not just the headers. So we downloaded the kernel source via the centos src rpm.

However the autoconf.h is missing.

We tried

- Put the .config in place (copied the one from /boot).
- run `make oldconfig`

So what is creating the autoconf.h file? Do we actually have to build the kernel?

Comment: In case someone is using Kconfig as build architecture for a project not related to Linux, the answer to this question is a bit different: to generate autoconf.h you need ./kconfig-frontends/frontends/conf/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The file `include/generated/autoconf.h` is generated in the `make prepare` step. If you are trying to build a kernel module, you will also need the `make scripts` step:

```
gunzip < /proc/config.gz > .config
make oldconfig
make prepare
make scripts
```

Usually the kernel is accompied with a headers package, have you tried installing that first? For CentOS, try installing the `kernel-devel` package. Details can be found on http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we had the headers package installed, but for some reasons the configure script was demanding the full source. We used the wiki page you linked.

Comment: Just for completeness: on CentOS the kernel config is located in `/boot` (compare with `uname -r` to select the right one).

Comment: @Stefan On some distros (like Arch Linux) it is located in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config` (`build` usually symlinks to `/usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)`), others use `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` (such as Ubuntu, Debian and apparently CentOS). If enabled during compilation, it is also available from `/proc/config.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

The file `autoconf.h` is automatically generated during the build process from the `.conf` file. 
Many kernel source files use `autoconf.h`.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  We prefer additional answers to address the question in a way that previous answers did not, or provide a better solution.